# Laravel Mail Facade: How to Send to Array of Recipients Individually?

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am trying to determine how to send an email to a group of recipients (as an array) through Laravel's Mail facade, but I would like the emails sent as individual emails as opposed to one bulk email in which all recipients' emails will be viewable.

I have an array of email addresses, $attendees, to whom the email is sent once validation passes. One way I could resolve this is to send to $attendees as 'bcc' vs. 'to,' but ideally I would like the email to be sent 'to' each recipient.

First and foremost, this following block of code DOES work, and is successful at emailing the array of $attendees -- but again, they all receive the email together and are able to view the collection of email addresses/emails of other recipients in the 'to' field when they receive the email, which I do not want to be the case.

```
  if ($validator->fails()) {
      $messages = $validator->messages();
      return Redirect::to(URL::previous())
          ->withErrors($validator)
          ->with('subject', $mailDetails['subject'])
          ->with('body', $body)
          ->with('eventId', $eventId);
  } else {
      Mail::send('emails.event_attendees', $mailBody, function($m) use ($mailDetails) {
          $m->from('noreply@helpinghabit.com', $mailDetails['orgName']);
          $m->to($mailDetails['attendees']);
          $m->bcc($mailDetails['sender']);
          $m->subject($mailDetails['subject']);
      });
      return redirect()->back()->with('message', "Your email has been sent!");
  };
```

I tried to accomplish this using a foreach loop like so:

```
  if ($validator->fails()) {
      $messages = $validator->messages();
      return Redirect::to(URL::previous())
          ->withErrors($validator)
          ->with('subject', $mailDetails['subject'])
          ->with('body', $body)
          ->with('eventId', $eventId);
  } else {
    foreach ($attendees as $k) {
      Mail::send('emails.event_attendees', $mailBody, function($m) use ($mailDetails) {
          $m->from('noreply@helpinghabit.com', $mailDetails['orgName']);
          $m->to($attendees[$k]);
          $m->bcc($mailDetails['sender']);
          $m->subject($mailDetails['subject']);
      });
    };
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', "Your email has been sent!");
  };
```

... but this returns an empty response error and tells me that no data was sent.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: did you try creating email notification class ?

Comment: Have you tried using a collection of users for the `to` field? From [Laravel Mail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#sending-mail): "_The `to` method accepts an email address, a user instance, or a collection of users. If you pass an object or collection of objects, the mailer will automatically use their email and name properties when setting the email recipients_" Not sure if they get sent individual mails though